# functions deployment fails: yarn: not found

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Recently our ability to deploy our functions, both in our dev and prod projects, ceased. When I attempt to deploy any function, or, via cloudbuild trigger, deploy all functions, I get an error:

```
Build failed: > functions@0.1.0 build
> yarn build-deps && tsc

sh: 1: yarn: not found; Error ID: 1a2262f3
```

functions@0.1.0 is the package in our repo. `yarn build-deps && tsc` is our package.json script called "build" .

1. this just started happening. There were two things that were happening at the same time:

   - we suddenly used a LOT of storage, in one of our GCS buckets. This GCS bucket usage doesn't **seem** related.
   - we attempted to redeploy one of the functions while it was being called with high frequency, with result that the deployment failed. But now it seems we cannot deploy **any** function.
2. This error is occurring in the functions deployment cloud -- not as part of our build, either local or GCB. It is during a functions.v1.OperationMetadataV1 UPDATE_FUNCTION. So, like, why is the function deployment running an `npm build` ?

Comment: Same, I wonder if they broke something ... status dashboard says auth is down.. wonder if its related: 

https://status.firebase.google.com/

Comment: Seems to be back working now. (haven't changed anything)

Comment: Not for me. Its been broken for several days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a breaking change where deploying would cause the package.json build script to be run. And apparently yarn is not installed by default.

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/release-notes#April_11_2023

Answer (score 2):

Yarn is used if your project includes a yarn.lock file.

Npm run build is run in default whenever a script is specified inside the package.json file. You can override this and only run your preferred scripts using custom build steps. You can use the `GOOGLE_NODE_RUN_SCRIPTS`
environment variable or `gcp-build` in your package.json file, these will control what scripts run. You can also specify one or more scripts, or instead pass an empty environment variable to prevent the default behaviour from running,`GOOGLE_NODE_RUN_SCRIPTS=`

For more information, you may refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/docs/buildpacks/nodejs#using_yarn).

You may also check this possible related [issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpacks/issues/287).

Answer (score 0):

**Update your Firebase CLI:** `npm install -g firebase-tools`

As other answers have mentioned, Google Cloud Functions now runs [`npm run build` during deployment](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/release-notes#April_11_2023).

However, as per [this comment by colerogers](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpacks/issues/287#issuecomment-1536373261), the Firebase team patched their CLI to disable this feature in firebase-tools v11.27.0. "If you upgrade to at least that version, this error should go away without any additional work."